# MassTransit fault handling configuration

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a problem with configuring a fault consumer in my app. The problem is that consumed message is passed to an `*_error_skipped` queue and it doesn't disappear entirely.

Below is a very simple example. The client app receives failed message and it disappear from a `test_error` queue but it still exists on the `test_error_skipped` queue.

Service project

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GreenPipes;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Util;

namespace MassTransitTest.Service
{

    public class RequestModel
    {
        public DateTime RequestTime { get; set; }
    }

    class MassTransitService : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _busControl;
        public MassTransitService()
        {
            _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configure =>
            {
                var host = configure.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/mt_test"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });
                configure.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test", c =>
                {
                    c.UseRetry(r => r.None());
                    c.Consumer<RequestConsumer>();
                });
            });
            TaskUtil.Await(_busControl.StartAsync());
            Console.WriteLine("bus started");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _busControl?.StopAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

    class RequestConsumer : IConsumer<RequestModel>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RequestModel> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"request with message id {context.MessageId} received: {context.Message.RequestTime}");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Client project

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GreenPipes;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Util;
using MassTransitTest.Service;

namespace MassTransitTest.Client
{
    class MassTransitClient
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _busControl;

        public MassTransitClient()
        {
            _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configure =>
            {
                var host = configure.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/mt_test"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                }); enter code here
                configure.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_error", c =>
                {
                    c.Consumer<ErrorConsumer>();
                });
            });
            TaskUtil.Await(_busControl.StartAsync());
            Console.WriteLine("bus started");
        }

        public async Task Send()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sending request");

            await (await _busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/mt_test/test"))).Send(new RequestModel()
            {
                RequestTime = DateTime.Now
            });
            Console.WriteLine("request sent");

        }
    }
    class ErrorConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<RequestModel>>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<RequestModel>> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"request with message id {context.Message.FaultedMessageId} failed. requested time: {context.Message.Message.RequestTime}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using .net core 2.1.1 and MassTransit 5.1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, which has several parts, first:

MassTransit receive endpoints move the message to the `_error` queue when an exception is thrown by the consumer. Creating a receive endpoint on the `_error` queue is not suggested, and should not be done.

If you simply want to observe if a fault occurred on the consumer, you can create a separate receive endpoint (such as *fault-queue*) and register your `Fault<T>` consumer. MassTransit will publish a message that implements `Fault<T>`, which the broker will route to your consumer via the receive endpoint.

However, based on your example above, you're sending a request and expecting the client to know if a fault occurred. For this, I'd recommend using the request client - which sets up the message headers to return faults back to the request originator. It also allows responses to be sent. If you don't want to wait for the response, or wait to see if the fault occurred, the above fault observer is your best option.

You can see how to use the request client in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html).

Comment: I'm looking for some documentation on how to properly consume messages stuck in the `_error` queues, using MT. I have try explicitely aiming for those queues using MT, but it intentionnaly moves them into a `_error_skipped` queue. My point is to successfully move from one topology that didn't handle errors correctly, to one that does, while gracefully handle the stuck messages.

Comment: While you can consume messages from error queues, it isn't highly recommended. It's better to use a tool to move those messages into a different queue for reprocessing (sometimes the original queue, but care should be taken to avoid messages being moved too many times). Also, if you're getting skipped messages, you aren't consuming the message types which are in the error queue.